# Upper bound of specific function: $\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^x$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, maxima-minima

Could you suggest an idea to find the upper bound of the following function:
$$\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^x,$$ where $x\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

Comment: Have you looked at its logarithm? BTW what does this have to do with [tag:power-series]?

Comment: $(1/x-1)^x=e^{xLn(1/x+1)}$ take the derivative of the second side and set it equal to zero.

Comment: I suppose that you will need some numerical method to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use implicit differentiation to find derivative of $y=(\dfrac{1}{x}-1)^x$ and find its zero(s) and examine sign of derivative between zeros to find where the function increases and where it decreases. If it does not have zero(s), then derivative is either positive or negative on interval $(0,\dfrac{1}{2}]$ and the upper bound should be easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Lower Bound: $(2x)^{-x}$ and Upper Bound: $x^{-x}$ for $x\in [0,0.5]$.

We know that $x\leq \frac{1}{2}$, so, $\frac{1}{x}\geq 2$. Then, $\frac{1}{x}-1\geq 2-1=1$. Also, we know that  $\frac{1}{x}\geq \frac{1}{x}-1\geq 1$. Now we just raise both sides of the inequlity to the power of  $x$ we have;
$(\frac{1}{x})^x\geq (\frac{1}{x}-1)^x$. Then $(\frac{1}{x})^x$ is an upper bound on [0,0.5].

Comment: Hi, how did you reach these lower and upper bound. Could you please show calculations.

Comment: I have updated my answer and given you more details. For the lower bound, please try. Your question was about upper bound :).